# Calico CNI in eks and StateFulSets

Tags: amazon-eks, calico

I started using Calico CNI v3.20.0 on eks cluster.
I installed it using the following
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico-vxlan.yaml

All looks good except pods that are part of statefulset can't seem to resolve DNS properly
I tried to use the workaround for Calico which is set hostNetwork: true

but this did not work for STS and did work for deployment though

anyone ran into this issue or knows how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you found a known issue.
Checkout this answer https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4866#issuecomment-904630688

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.